# How to get matrix $A$ knowing that $A^2 = O_2$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

> Given a matrix $$A =  \left[\begin{matrix} a & b  \\ c & d \\  \end{matrix}\right],$$
>   how do you solve the equations of $$A^2 = \left[\begin{matrix} a^2 + bc & b(a+d)  \\ c(a+d) & d^2 + cb \\  \end{matrix}\right] = O_2?$$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Your system is$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a^2+bc=0\\b(a+d)=0\\c(a+d)=0\\d^2+bc=0.\end{array}\right.$$If $a=-d$, this system becomes simply $a^2+bc=0$.

If $d\neq-a$, then $b=c=0$. And then it follows from the first and fourth equation that $a=d=0$ too.

So, the solutions of your matrix equation are the matrices of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ such that $a^2+bc=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$A\in M_2(K)$ is nilpotent if and only if $\det(A)=\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$ by Cayley-Hamilton. This means $a+d=0$ and $a^2+bc=0$.